# Flatmap scala [String, String,List[String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, extract, rdd, flatmap

I have this prbolem, I have an `RDD[(String,String,  List[String])`, and I would like to "flatmap" it to obtain a `RDD[(String,String,  String)]`:

e.g:

```
val x :RDD[(String,String,  List[String]) = 
RDD[(a,b, list[ "ra", "re", "ri"])]
```

I would like get:

```
val result: RDD[(String,String,String)] = 
RDD[(a, b, ra),(a, b, re),(a, b, ri)])]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", "b", List("ra", "re", "ri"))))
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, List[String])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[7] at parallelize at <console>:28

rdd.flatMap{ case (x, y, z) => z.map((x, y, _)) }.collect
// res23: Array[(String, String, String)] = Array((a,b,ra), (a,b,re), (a,b,ri))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way of doing it using `flatMap` again

```
val rdd  =  sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("a", "b", List("ra", "re", "ri"))))
rdd.flatMap(array => array._3.map(list => (array._1, array._2, list))).foreach(println)
```

Comment: I do not agree, the type of result here would be `RDD[List[(String, String, String)]]` while the OP asks for `RDD[(String, String, String)]`

Comment: Yes you are right @GPI let me update my answer :) thanks for letting me know